# Docker compose, accessing a Postgres container from an other container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have this really simple setup with a web app in one container and a Postgres service running in another container.

I need to connect to the Postgres container and thought `PGHOST="db"` would point to that container ..?

But I keep getting `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND "db" at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup` that I read as; can't find the "db" host ...

What am I missing here?

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:3011"
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - PGHOST="db"
      - PGDATABASE="testdb"
      - PGUSER="postgres"
      - PGPASSWORD="postgres"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/var/postgresql@13
```

Comment: Pretty sure this was already answered somewhere else, but you don't need the `"` around db

Comment: if you want to use quotes you should quote the full string and not just a part of it, but in YAML you don't need quotes most of the time.

Comment: Isschh .. ‍♂️ Of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this config. You don't need quotes when passing env variables. And it is better to use `depends_on` here to make sure DB is up and running before your app starts.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:3011"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - PGHOST=db
      - PGDATABASE=testdb
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/var/postgresql@13
```

Comment: You may want to add a `depends_on` clause for the `web` service.
I'm not sure if the `links` clause is needed here

Comment: @Hollyol, thanks edited the answer.

Comment: its better to design the app to work without `depends_on` with retry logic and things like that.

Comment: `depends_on:` doesn't actually ensure the database is up and running; see [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y).  (It does avoid a DNS-lookup error and is generally good practice, though.)